# Access 1 silverlight application from another

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-4.0

I have two silverlight applications.

I want to reference the first one from the second one (almost like an iframe) and have them interact.

How might I do this?

For example, can I reference the other application's xap file in my first application?

I do not want them to communicate with each other externally.  I actually want to use the second application like a 3rd party library to the first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to communicate through a messaging API, not actually reference the other XAP directly.  They run in different sandboxes and you'd be delegating through marshaling or messaging anyways (if such a thing actually existed).

This is what you want:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd833063(v=vs.95).aspx